# AWS Cognito forgotPassword strange response when user does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-identity-js

I'm using `amazon-cognito-identity-js` to reset user password. I call `user.forgotPassword()` and that all works fine, the user receives a verification code, etc.

However, something strange happens when I enter a non-existing username!

I do everything properly, I create a `user = new CognitoUser(...)` object with my pool and some random username. And then, when I call `user.forgotPassword(...)`, `onSuccess` is triggered, and I get something like this as a response:

`CodeDeliveryDetails: Object { AttributeName: "phone_number", DeliveryMedium: "SMS", Destination: "+*******5651" }`

or, if I insist on email recovery instead of SMS:

`CodeDeliveryDetails: Object { AttributeName: "email", DeliveryMedium: "EMAIL", Destination: "4***@g***" }`

Is Cognito really sending random people SMSs and emails?!?
I swear I don't have users with any similar email or phone in my User Pool. O_o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common security feature for avoiding user enumeration, ie, identify if a given username/email is valid in the platform, which can lead to attacks like brute-forcing or credential stuffing.

In order to avoid this vulnerability, it is recommended that the response content (and timing) to operations like sign in, sign up and password reset is the same for valid or invalid usernames and this is what Cognito is doing by sending a *fake* response stating that a code has been sent to a simulated email address or phone number, but none is sent.

From Cognito Developer Guide on [Managing error responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-managing-errors.html#:%7E:text=ForgotPassword,the%20user%20pool.):

> **ForgotPassword**
>
> When a user isn't found, is deactivated, or doesn't have a verified delivery mechanism to recover their password, Amazon
> Cognito returns `CodeDeliveryDetails` with a simulated delivery medium
> for a user. The simulated delivery medium is determined by the input
> user name format and verification settings of the user pool.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! That actually makes a lot of sense...

Comment: OK but how do you handle this case if you want to notify the user that they have i.e. misspelled their e-mail if the response is identical as a success response?

Comment: This behavior is configurable though, if you have the option "Prevent user existence errors" set to `false`, then Cognito will report it as an error.