# Cognito reset password weird behaviour for the new users: wrong email in CodeDeliveryDetails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, reset-password

I created a new user in AWS Cognito using the AWS Console, and it's currently in a "Force change password" state.

[image]

I want to trigger the 'forgotten password' flow immediately without inserting a username and password. So, I executed this Postman request:

```bsh
curl --location 'https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/' \
--header 'X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.ForgotPassword' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1' \
--data '{
    "ClientId":"aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbcccccccdd",
    "Username":"brandnewuser"
}'
```

However, I received this response:

```json
{
    "CodeDeliveryDetails": {
        "AttributeName": "email",
        "DeliveryMedium": "EMAIL",
        "Destination": "t***@y***"
    }
}
```

The issue is that the (masked) email is incorrect; it should be something like `a***@a***` instead of `t***@y***`. This can confuse our clients.

Do you have any insights into why this is happening or have you encountered a similar problem? What steps should I take, such as opening a ticket with AWS?

Thank you for your assistance.
Ennio

Comment: `t***@y***` - where is that from? is that another users? random email? a bit more context is needed here. same domain? completely different domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user is in the `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` state it's not possible to use the ForgotPassword API, as per [AWS re:Post Knowledge Center](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-forgot-password):

> **The user isn't in a CONFIRMED status**
>
> Users created by administrators are in a FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD status by default until they sign in with the password provided. Then, users are prompted to change the password.
>
> If the user status is FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD, then the ForgotPassword API call can't be used and the verification code isn't sent.

The reason why you are seeing the `t***@y***` email address is a security feature to avoid user enumeration (more info on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74001111/3610403) and [Cognito Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-managing-errors.html#cognito-user-pool-managing-errors-password-reset)), if you disable `PreventUserExistenceErrors` you'll see the actual error message:
`{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"User password cannot be reset in the current state."}`